# How to restrict the user from entering negative number, in an cellEditable material-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, material-table

I am using material table cellEditable in my project and I want to restrict users from entering negative no in the field. also, throw error validation. I am able to achieve that in "editable" but not on cellEditable How to achieve that??

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h1f8d?file=/demo.js:609-979

```
 <MaterialTable
      title="Cell Editable Preview"
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      cellEditable={{
        onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("newValue: " + newValue);
            setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
          });
        }
      }}
    />
```

Comment: @codemonkey not allow to enter negative no....